# what attributes can I set in Matplotlib's function ax.set()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

From the Matplotlib's official website I can get that the function 'ax.set()' can bset attributes.But I haven't known what attributes can I set actually.For instance:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib 

fig=plt.figure(
figsize=(15,6),
dpi=120,
    )

#definition layout
layout=(2,4)

#create
axes=fig.subplots(*layout)


ax_plot_function=axes[0][0] 
ax_scatter=axes[0][1] 
    
#plot the first axes
props = {
        'title': 'function_example$f(x)=cos(x)$', 
        'xlabel': 'X',
        'ylabel':'Y',
        'xlim':(-(2*np.pi),2*np.pi),
        'ylim':(-(np.pi),np.pi),
        'grid':True,
      } 
ax_plot_function.set(**props)
x=np.arange(-(2*np.pi),2*np.pi,0.01)
y=np.cos(x)


ax_plot_function.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

in Line29 happens an error that says

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no property 'grid'
```

So I know that the function 'set()' can not have the attribute 'grid' in Line27,But how can I fix it and What attributes can I set exactly by using the function 'ax.set()'.
Could I get a list of all attributes that can set by the function 'set()'? Or Please tell me where I can find the list.

Comment: you can have a look at the [axis class documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis) for the attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ax.set()` can set the properties defined in class [matplotlib.axes.Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/axes_api.html).

There is also `set_xxx()` api where `xxx` is also the property in class *matplotlib.axes.Axes*.

The idea is simple, image you create a Python class and some properties. The related `getter` and `setter` method should be defined. Also, the constructor method can take initial values of those properties.

If you want to turn on the grid, use [`ax.grid(True)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid).